# How to apply a class based on the content being upper or lower case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to select multiple `<div>` elements with the class `.choice` and then check if the contents are all uppercase OR if the contents are all lowercase. Based on if its contents are all lowercase or uppercase i then want to apply a CSS class.

I've been trying to use Jquery/Javascript to do this however I'am very new to both languages.

The Jquery i used was along the lines of:

```
$(".choice").text()
// and also
$(".choice").text().isUppercase().addClass()
```

But i'm pretty sure i can't use JavaScript and Jquery in this manner.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and the results (maybe in a jsfiddle).

Comment: @Sfili_81 there is an example of what the OP tried in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can provide a function to `addClass()` which checks the case of the text in the current element and returns the class to add based on what it finds. Try this:

```js
$(".choice").addClass(function() {
  var t = $(this).text();
  if (t.toUpperCase() === t) 
    return 'upper';
  else if (t.toLowerCase() === t)
    return 'lower'    
});
```

```css
.upper { color: #C00; }
.lower { color: #0C0;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choice">ALL UPPERCASE</div>
<div class="choice">Both Cases</div>
<div class="choice">all lowercase</div>
```

Note that the `if` condition can be shortened using the below ternary statement. It's a personal preference if you prefer brevity over readability:

```
return t.toUpperCase() === t ? 'upper' : t.toLowerCase() === t ? 'lower' : null;
```